# How do i open a pop up window which is scrolled to a fixed position (everytime the page in the pop up finishes loading would be perfect) inside

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a pop up window and want to scroll the page inside. It only needs to scroll like 10-20 pixels to the right when it opens.
I'm opening the pop up window with:

`popUp = window.open("URL", "_blank", "top=0,left=100");`

and now I want the page to be scrolled slightly.
It has scrollbars and I can scroll it manually but not with JavaScript like `scroll()` , `scrollTo()` or `scrollBy()` .

Wanted to have the popUp do that everytime it reloads but its not even scrolling when i open it so i dont need to start with that and i dont find someone else who had the same problem with a fix
Im using Google Chrome and im not to sure if the page in the pop up has the same domain (I dont believe so)

I tried :

`popUp.scroll(10, 0);`,
`popUp.scrollTo(10, 0);`,
`popUp.scrollBy(10, 0);`,
`popUp.scroll({top: 0, left: 10, behavior: "auto"});`

but nothing works on the popUp window even though they would work on the main window...

Comment: So the scroll code is in the pop up window? Or are you trying to scroll the page from the  opener page? If it is a different domain, you can not touch the pop up window.

Comment: i want to scroll the page in the pop up, the page inside is a page like google.com, im not too sure what u mean with opener page im quite new to JavaScript

Comment: That is impossible to do with JavaScript because of the same origin policy. Domain A can not access Domain B. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy